# Avoid duplicate mail content in Email Sync

Tags: email, gmail-imap, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail API for email synchronization in my app.

While a conversation is in progress, previous reply is also attached along with current mail that increases message content and leads to duplicate content over and over again.

I want to avoid this duplication but can't figure out the right way to do it.
I'm extracting text/plain part(if unavailable : text/html) from emails.

I tried getting substring but duplicate content isn't an exact match. It includes ">", ">> ", " >>--", "> " symbols at random.

Comment: You can use Gmail Partial synchronization for this. If your application has synchronized recently, you can perform a partial sync using the history.list method to return all history records newer than the startHistoryId you specify in your request. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync

Comment: @SGC : I'm not talking about duplicate mail, but duplicate contents in mail that are visible by clicking "show trimmed content" in Gmail message thread.